# Websocketpp: Address already in use

Tags: c++, websocket

I am using websocketpp to run a websocket server. However, when I close the application and start it again, I get the error:

```
[info] asio listen error: system:98 (Address already in use)
```

It seems like I have to set `reuse_address` in the asio socket. I have not found any documentation how to do it.

How can I let the websocket server reuse the address?

Comment: In ancient times, I got this error in a similar situation (but using basic socket functions). Finally, I found out that my application didn't close/shutdown the sockets properly. Instead, the OS (IRIX) did it for me (after exit of the resp. process) but not before a certain timeout of roundabout 30 seconds. (After I got bothered about waiting I finally digged deeper and fixed it...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this help page](https://docs.websocketpp.org/singletonwebsocketpp_1_1transport_1_1asio_1_1endpoint.html#a13784d09af030a55e85faaf8f111fdc3) it looks like there is a `set_reuse_addr()` function exposed, this may help?

Synopsis:

```
void set_reuse_addr (bool value)
```

> Specifies whether or not to use the SO_REUSEADDR TCP socket option.
>   What this flag does depends on your operating system.
>
> Please consult operating system documentation for more details. There
>   may be security consequences to enabling this option.
>
> New values affect future calls to listen only so set this value prior
>   to calling listen.
>
> The default is false.